# Find $x- \frac 1x$ when $x + \frac 1x = 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When

$$x + \frac 1x = 3,$$

Evaluate the exact value of

$$x - \frac 1x .$$

PS. I know the answer is $\pm\sqrt 5$.

Comment: $\left(x-\frac 1x\right)^2=\left(x+\frac 1x\right)^2-4$.

Comment: Is there a particular method you want? Multiplying both sides of your given equation by $x$ gives you a quadratic equation that you can easily solve. Then substitute the two values of $x$ into your new expression. Is something wrong with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x-\frac{1}{x})^2=(x+\frac{1}{x})^2-4$

I hope you can take it further.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$x + 1 / x = 3,$$
$$x^2 + 1 = 3x,$$
$$x = \cdots$$
$$x - 1 / x = \cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

Use Newton's theorem for symmetric functions:

*Any symmetric rational function of $n$ variables $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ can be expressed as a rational function of the elementary symmetric functions 
\begin{align*}
s_1&=x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n\\s_2&=\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}x_ix_j\\\vdots\\
s_n&=x_1x_2\dotsm x_n
\end{align*}
Fot $2$ variables, this mans a symmetric function is indeed a function of $s=x_1+x_2$ and $p=x_1x_2$:
$$\Bigl(x-\frac1x\Bigr)^2=\Bigl(x+\frac1x\Bigr)^2-4=5.$$

Comment: Could you quote that theorem? Do you mean [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities)?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

From $$a+\frac{1}{a}=3$$, this will reduce to a quadratic equation in terms of a as

$$a^2-3a+1=0$$

Do the math, solve for a and proceed.